# Análise sintática da frase "Está na hora de sair"?

Tags: sintaxe

A frase: "Está na hora de sair" apresenta dois verbos e portanto duas orações. Qual o valor da oração que tem o verbo "sair"? Eu penso que ela poderia ser escrita como: "Está na hora em que eu saio" e aí teríamos uma oração adjetiva restritiva.

Comment: Oração subordinada completiva nominal?!?!?!

Comment: Esse seria o caso mais difícil de se dizer. Normalmente, complemento nominal sucede um substantivo abstrato. Hora não pode ser um substantivo abstrato nesse caso porque ele é sinônimo de momento e instante.  Por exemplo, a frase "Ele parou naquele momento" ou "Ele parou naquela hora" estão bem definidas. Eu não acho que o complemento nominal faça muito sentido nessa estrutura também se pensar na parte do paciente porque quem sai é a pessoa e não a hora.